# Hazelcast not able to read data into my own class object using IMap.get, where data inserted using Memcached text protocol

Tags: java, c, memcached, hazelcast

I am inserting record into Hazelcast from C Application using Memcached Client Library API's, where record is as follows:

```
typedef struct _activeClient
{
    char ID[25];
    int  IP;
    char aMethod[16];
}activeClient;
```

Now I am trying reading same record using Hazelcast Java Native API's. Here is my Java program.

```
IMap < String, MemcacheEntry > mapInst = client.getMap("hz_memcache_ABC_MAP");
System.out.println("Map Size:" + mapInst.size());
String key = new String("70826892122991");
MemcacheEntry tmpValRec = pvrMapIst.get(key);
System.out.println("Key:" + key + "ID:" + tmpValRec.getValue());
```

Here `tmpValRec.getValue()` printing record content in single String format. But, I want to retrive each member value from `tmpValRec` to my own java class object. Here is the class

```
class ActiveClients
{
    String ueID;
    int Ip;
    String aMethod;
    ActiveClients()
    {
        ueID = "";
        Ip = 0;
        aMethod = "";
    }
}
```

Pointing me to an example would be great help.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the only option is to parse the string to deserialize your object. I know this is a pain, but I don't see a better alternative. Unless of course you store a blob as a value in memcached where the blob is the serialized content of the class.

Comment: Thank you Pveentjer for your inputs.